# Python progressbar inside a for loop which read files number

Tags: python, progress-bar

Using the progressbar library :

```
import progressbar
.
.
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(files_total)).start()
```

This is my base for loop to read and store all .txt files in path4safe (which is a local test folder with 200 .txt file), which also tell me how many text files there is in the folder with a "d"

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(path4safe):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(tuple(ext)):
            d += 1
            files_total.append(root + "/" + x)
```

So I tried this :

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(path4safe):
    for idx, files in enumerate(files_total):
        for x in files:
            if x.endswith(tuple(ext)):
                d += 1
                files_total.append(root + "/" + x)
                bar.update(idx)
```

But I only get an empty progress bar, I feel like I'm mixing up one of my var. Basically I'm trying to use "d" to create the progressbar.

```
[]0% |                                                                                                                |

Total files:
0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: could you by any change switch to using [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) instead ? the package you currently use hasn't been maintained in years.

Comment: to be honest, it is working, it's just doing too much updates with much overhead it doesn't look like it's working, so consider changing it to tqdm.